# JS Logic Explaination for some lines

Tags: javascript, minify, deobfuscation

could someone explain me the logic behind these lines?

It is an onkeyup event. I don't know the value of r.

```
return $("#commentText").val() ?
(0==r&&(r=!0,setTimeout( function(){r=!1},1e4),socket.emit('status', connectiondetails)),void 0)
: !1
```

What does stand alone `r=!0` do? What does `function(){r!=1}` do?

What is `!1` as a return value?

is `!1` == `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be obfuscated or minified code.

```
return $("#commentText").val() ?
(0==r&&(r=!0,setTimeout( function(){r=!1},1e4),socket.emit('status', connectiondetails)),void 0)
: !1
```

becomes (as best I can figure it):

```
if ($("#commentText").val()) {
    if(0==r) {
        r = true;
        setTimeout( 
            function(){ r = false},1000
        );
        socket.emit('status', connectiondetails)
    }
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Some mappings that are used:

```
true        -> !0     (saves 2 characters)
false       -> !1     (saves 3 characters)
if(x) { y } -> x && y (saves 5 characters)
1000        -> 1e4    (saves 1 character)
```